# How do I use tkinter, ttk and ttkbootstrap styles at the same time without one overriding the other?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, styles, ttk

I have written a simple Hangman app with tkinter graphics and I'm trying to make it better by using ttkbootstrap.

The problem is, I have created a grid where all the letters of the alphabet show as ttk.Buttons, for the user to choose. When I only import
`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
```

`
buttons show just fine inside the grid. But when I add "import ttkbootstrap", or even "from ttkbootstrap import Style", without changing anything else in my code an no matter if this is the first import in the list or last (after tkinter and ttk), when I run the code, the buttons do not fit inside the grid/their frame anymore and even minimizing their width messes them up even more. They also show blue but I don't care much about this.

Here's the snippet of the code that creates the grid (every other thing works perfectly with letter selection etc.):

`

```
    if word_selected.split()[1][-2] in german_alphabet:
        for letter in german_alphabet:
            if german_alphabet.index(letter) < 6:
                ttk.Button(letter_frame, text=str(letter), width=2, command=lambda letter=letter: select_letter(
                    letter)).grid(row=1, column=german_alphabet.index(letter), sticky=W)
            elif german_alphabet.index(letter) >= 6 and german_alphabet.index(letter) < 12:
                ttk.Button(letter_frame, text=str(letter), width=2, command=lambda letter=letter: select_letter(
                    letter)).grid(row=2, column=(german_alphabet.index(letter)-6), sticky=W)
            elif german_alphabet.index(letter) >= 12 and german_alphabet.index(letter) < 18:
                ttk.Button(letter_frame, text=str(letter), width=2, command=lambda letter=letter: select_letter(
                    letter)).grid(row=3, column=(german_alphabet.index(letter)-12), sticky=W)
            elif german_alphabet.index(letter) >= 18 and german_alphabet.index(letter) < 24:
                ttk.Button(letter_frame, text=str(letter), width=2, command=lambda letter=letter: select_letter(
                    letter)).grid(row=4, column=(german_alphabet.index(letter)-18), sticky=W)
            elif german_alphabet.index(letter) >= 24:
                ttk.Button(letter_frame, text=str(letter), width=2, command=lambda letter=letter: select_letter(
                    letter)).grid(row=5, column=(german_alphabet.index(letter)-24), sticky=W)
```

`and here's the frame they are put into:`

```
letter_frame = Frame(letter_attempts_frame, borderwidth=2,
                     relief="sunken", width=150, height=320, bg='yellow')  # 100 -200
```

`
I guess the problem is that importing ttkbootstrap style overrides ttk button or frame styles and thus buttons do not fit inside their frame anymore. Any ideas on how to avoid this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Already tried importing tkinter, ttk and ttkbootstrap in different order. Also imported full ttkbootstrap and only Style from it. Also tried to change everything inside my code to e.g. tk.Frame/ttk.Frame and ttkbootstrap.Frame instead of Frame, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent ttkbootstrap to apply a theme to your legacy widget, you'll first have to use the legacy widget (seems like you already do) and also use the parameter `autostyle=False`

Example:

```
import ttkbootstrap as tkb
import tkinter as tk

root = tkb.Window()

tkb.Button(root, text='Test Button 1').pack()
tkb.Button(root, text='Test Button 2').pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Test Button 3', autostyle=False).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I use tk for the legacy button and remove the styling with `autostyle=False`